# Android GoogleApiClient connects to MARSHMALLOW but not to JELLY_BEAN

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

My Android app dumps files into Gdrive. It's using Oauth2.0 authentication and I've done the needful at console.developers.google.com. The problem I'm facing is that the app works fine on my Marshmallow phone but cannot get past the Google login on my JellyBean or lower. On these, the app gets stuck at the "Choose account for" window.

Studio's Android monitor returns the following:

```
GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{419cbb80 ...
```

Keeping in mind that the app does work on the Marshmallow phone, my suspicion is that the issue is related to one of the "versions" in the app's build.grade file, an excerpt of which is below.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "rudy.android.stgpro"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 18
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.rudykeystore
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.rudykeystore
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
}
```

Or, maybe, Oauth2.0 does not work with earlier Android versions.

I also notice that the size of the app loaded into Marshmallow is about 40% the size of that loaded into the other two phones.

Google's Drive app works fine on all phones.

I've googled around for hours now and am, pretty much, stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Jelly Bean is Android 16 version, but your targetSdkVersion is set to 18. Try setting it to 16, according to [Android 4.1 APIs docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html). Make sure Android studio has  the necessary updates for Android 16 also.

Comment: Tried ... no luck. In fact, I've tried a number of combinations of compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, play-services-drive without joy.

Answer (score 0):

After much "blood, sweat and tears", I've discovered that the problem lay in a single line in the AndroidManifest.xml file ...

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

I have no clue why this line affects phones running JellyBean and lower but not Marshmallow (not sure about Kitkat & Lollipop). And, just to be clear, the line literally toggles the problem with  its presence/absence  (with zero other changes).

I zeroed in on the problem using [Drives's Quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) as a base (its connection worked with all my test phones), then gradually modifying its code by adding/removing from my app's code (took me a couple of days).

Anyway, thank goodness for these working samples.